# How can I get all the contents from all the <img> tags using regex? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

im building a notebloc and im using a rich text editor, the problem with this is that the editor uses html tags, so when I insert an image it will be: `<img src="file....">`, so now I need to know which image the user deleted when was editing the note, to do that i thounght getting all the uri from the actual content and compare them to the array of uri saved before, but to that I need to use a regex (i think is the best) to get all the uris, so if theres three `<img>` tags, i want the string inside the `src`, these: `"file..''.....jpg"` incluiding both ``" " ```

Comment: Not with regex. Use DOMParser.

Comment: Something like this: https://gist.github.com/randycasburn/af5f2381387dfa324c8216273134b305